# Allow users to post comments in my site with their facebook account without creating an account inside my site for them?

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, authentication, account

Is there any way to allow people that has a facebook account to post comments in my site with their Facebook profile, but avoiding them to actually create a user account on my site?
I´m using Drupal, and didn´t find a module that does that. You can integrate Facebook, of course, but you *have* to let people that logs in with their Facebook account to create an account on your site.
I don´t want that. Is there any way of doing that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what the [Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) is for - one popular method of automatically adding this to Drupal pages is via the ['fb' module](http://drupal.org/project/fb)

Comment: Thanks! I haven´t tried that module because I´ve read that it was for creating Facebook applications, and I (thougth) that was not what I was looking for. I´m trying that now. THANKS!

Comment: I believe it also works with the social plugins (e.g. Like button and Comments plugin) - but i've never tried to use it myself. If that module isn't suitable you should be able to add the HTML necessary to trigger the plugin into your theme directly, but it's easier to use a module i think

Comment: In fact, that module says that it can do this: "Let users authenticate to your site using their facebook username and password. This saves the user the trouble of registering with your site, and allows you to build additional social features, known as Facebook Connect." I´ll try to avoid that, I don´t want a new user account on my site just because some user posted a comment on it.

Comment: The docs for the module are a bit sparse, but it does support adding the social plugins without needing to change your site's login (e.g. http://drupal.org/node/933670 )

Comment: I´ve tried to use the module, but in order to do so I need a facebook account with a cellphone verification. I´ve put my phone number, but facebook won´t send me any confirmation code...