# Commenting system like Mashable? (user comments with their external sites credentials without creating an account in your site)

Tags: facebook, drupal, twitter, credentials, drupal-comments

I´m struggling with comments. I have a site that has a commenting system, and I want people that has an account with FB, Twitter, or G+, to be able to post comments using those credentials.
The thing is that I want something like, let´s say, mashable, where people doesn´t have to create an account to post stuff.

They just log in to their accounts, and when posting the comment the site takes their avatar and name, and that´s it.

I don´t want them to crteate an account inside my site.

I´m using a Drupal site, and after reading a lot, and after asking a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189224/facebook-using-my-drupal-comments-system-and-fb-comments-all-at-the-same-time) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072060/allow-users-to-post-comments-in-my-site-with-their-facebook-account-without-crea), I still don´t know how to do that. I mean, it is possible because other sites have that. Right?

I need to implement something like disqus, but I want the comments to be stored inside my own database.

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenID](http://openid.net/). That's the system most websites with this functionality use (including StackExchange!). It allows you to authenticate the user with the service you want, without making the user create an account with you.

Here's an example of another site that uses OpenID: http://www.livejournal.com/identity/login.bml?type=google

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I think openid does work only for people with an openid account, is that correct? I mean, like Gravatar, for example.

Comment: There are a ton of services that use OpenID, including Google, Twitter, Facebook, and lots more.

Comment: Oh I see, so I´ll try that out then. I thougth they were different things. Thanks!